# How to join 3 table in laravel using eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

How can I  get some data from 3 table using eloquent in laravel 5?
I have 3 table, Lists, Card, User

Lists model

```
public function card()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Card::class);
    }
```

Card model

```
public function lists()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Lists::class);
    }

public function member()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)->withPivot('status','user_role')->withTimestamps();
    }
```

User model

```
public function card_member(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Card::class)->withTimestamps();
    }
```

I want to get List within card that assign to specific user (example user_id : 2)

Like this JSOn Data

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "boards_id": "1",
    "list_name": "List 2 B1 U1",
    "position": 2,
    "created_at": "2019-04-03 16:02:03",
    "updated_at": "2019-04-03 16:02:03",
    "card": [
      {
        "id": 8,
        "lists_id": "2",
        "card_title": "Card 3 L2",
        "labels": null,
        "description": null,
        "start_card": null,
        "end_card": null,
        "position": 2,
        "is_archieved": false,
        "created_at": "2019-04-26 15:34:22",
        "updated_at": "2019-04-26 15:34:22"
      },
      {
        "id": 9,
        "lists_id": "2",
        "card_title": "Card 4 L2",
        "labels": null,
        "description": null,
        "start_card": null,
        "end_card": null,
        "position": 3,
        "is_archieved": false,
        "created_at": "2019-04-26 15:34:25",
        "updated_at": "2019-04-26 15:34:25"
      }
```

Table structure : 
Lists :

```
id
boards_id
listname
position
```

Card :

```
id
lists_id
card_title
```

Card_user (pivot table):

```
id
card_id
user_id
```

Comment: can you share the table structure and explain brefily what are you trying to get

Comment: @Manojkiran.A pls check the edited  post, thankyou :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets change the relationship name from 'member' to 'members' because that is a many to many relationship.

```
public function members()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)->withPivot('status','user_role')->withTimestamps();
    }
```

You might say:

```
$userId = 2;

$lists = List::with([
    'card' => function ($query) {
        $query->whereHas('members', function ($query) user ($userId) {
            $query->whereKey($userId);
        })
    }
])
->whereHas('card.members', function ($query) use ($userId) {
    $query->whereKey($userId);
})
->get();
```

So we only eager load the cards having user id 2.

Comment: it works but the result is  it show all the card , not the card that assign for userId 2..

Comment: instead of `get()` use `first()` and it will return only matching value @JoshParinussa